# roslaunch ROSARIA problem

Tags: roslaunch, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all.

I can run:rosrun ROSARIA RosAria

But when I run the following in a launch file

I get the error:

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ROSARIA/RosAria]: ROSARIA

ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros

ROS path [1]=/home/acp/patrol_ws/sandbox

ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/share

ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks

ROS path [4]=/home/acp/patrol_ws

ROS path [5]=/home/acp/patrol_ws/skynetish/generic_teleop

Any clue about this?

I appreciate your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67074/roslaunch-rosaria-problem/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-07-11**:
Try out p2os-vanderbilt. It's stable in groovy. http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os-vanderbilt

**Comment by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) on 2013-08-03**:
is the folder in which the ROSARIA is located added to $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Man:
Maybe I know what is wrong with your launch file.
In my opinion, the value of the pkg attribute should be "rosaria" rather than "ROSARIA" becuz the name of the directory u put your source code in is "rosaria" .
So if u change  the value to "rosaria" ,the problem will be solved.
Hope u success!Best wishes~

Edward Chow

---

Originally posted by [Edward Chow](https://answers.ros.org/users/20259/edward-chow/) with karma: 26 on 2014-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0